# Android studio rendering issue with version 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

How could i fix the issue in android studio.
 "Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project."

Previously my project working fine but when i update my android studio by latest 1.2.1.1 this issue occur.
below is my xml file
`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <com.appnometry.cudoro.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_profile" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Hello">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mr. Customer Name" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:text="10 items in cart" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:text="|" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:text="04 Items in whitelist" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/leftmenu_divider" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/leftmenu_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"></ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_logout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="logout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Try to change Theme style AppCompact to Base.Theme.AppCompact from Theme drop down at top of preview.

Comment: Thanks. But Unfortunately Your solution is not working.

Comment: is still not showing preview ?

Comment: yes preview still not showing

Answer (score 0):

Select Android version to `21`, instead of `22` in preview window.